# Returning PDF file instead of binary data Zapier Developer platform

Tags: javascript, pdf, binaryfiles, zapier

Hello I want to change the way the data comes into my private Zapier app right now I'm getting the binary data as the response but that is not supported in the editor. is there a way to get the file to be usable in the Zapier Zap editor?